# what should be the parameters to method that CallMethodAction calls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I can't make it work. I get this error from the debugger:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Could not find method named 'ChaplinMovies' on object of type 'CommandsForContext' that matches the expected signature.'

```
namespace RandomMoviesPlayer
{
    public static class PlayChaplin
    {
        public static void PlayChap()
        {
            VideoAudioPlay(Constants.chaplinPath, Constants.chaplinLog);
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public void ChaplinMovies(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayChaplin.PlayChap();
        }

    }
}
```

```xml
<Button x:Name="Chaplin" Margin="10" Content="Chaplin">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
      <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ChaplinMovies" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Apparentely You don't need to have parameters in the method definition [here is SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26835703/2029607) to provide some more info. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26836022/2029607) is the answer to it look at the comments.

Comment: @XAMlMAX without the arguments the error message is exactly the same.

Comment: From the [MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xaml.interactions.core.callmethodaction.execute(v=vs.120).aspx) it seems that you need 2 parameters of type `Object`. BTW your `Button` xaml is missing closing `>`. And what is `CommandsForContext`?

Comment: From the error message it looks like that your DataContext is pointing to `CommandsForContext` and not to the `ViewModel` that contains that method.