# Loading a UserControl in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I am building a WPF MVVM application. I am trying to load a `UserControl` inside a Grid but the `OnLoaded` method doesn't fire.

Here is `EventTrigger` in the `UserControl`, called `Selector`:

```
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
        </b:EventTrigger>
</b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Here is the code in `SelectorViewModel`:

```
public RelayCommand OnLoadedCommand { get; set; }

public SelectorViewModel(MapService mapService)
{
      this.mapService = mapService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapService));

      OnLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(OnLoaded);
}

public async void OnLoaded()
{
      AvailablePositions = await mapService.GetPositions();
      //other code
}
```

The `View` of the grid where the `UserControl` is loaded into:

```
<local:Selector Grid.Row="0" Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftTopMargin}" />
```

The `ViewModel` of the grid, where the `UserControl` is loaded into:

```
public SelectorViewModel SelectorViewModel { get; set; }

public MapViewModel(MapService mapService)
{
      SelectorViewModel = new SelectorViewModel(mapService);
}
```

What could possibly be the reason the method is not called at all? I put a breakpoint in `SelectorViewModel`' s constructor and it hits it, but it doesn't hit the one in `OnLoaded()`.

Is the fact that the method is `async` a problem?

EDIT:

I tried setting the command as:

```
OnLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await OnLoaded());
```

and changing the return type of `OnLoaded` from `void` to `Task` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind it with `Command` like below. I tested it works.

**Xaml Code**

```
       <DataGrid>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public AsyncCommand OnLoadedCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            OnLoadedCommand = new AsyncCommand(async () => await OnLoaded());
        }

        public async Task OnLoaded()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loaded");
        }
    }
```

**Async Command**

```
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
}

public class AsyncCommand : AsyncCommandBase
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _command;
    public AsyncCommand(Func<Task> command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }
    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        return _command();
    }
}
```

**AsyncCommandBase**

```
public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
{
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);
    public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);
    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
}
```

I also recommend you to subscribe to Method as in the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835703/wpf-interaction-trigger-callmethodaction).

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands) for more detailed information.

Comment: It still doesn't work, not sure why, I edited my question with a full explanation.

Comment: I'm editing the answer for you.